# JavaFx chart multiple Series, how to make them keep separate

Tags: java, javafx, charts

I have 2 data series but the line looks like connecting each other and the first point connect to last point. how to make them separate ?

in sample site : http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/line-chart.htm#CIHGBCFI, the chart keep separate and line color change automaticaly.

is there something wrong with my code ? please help

this is my code :

```
class dataXY
{
 public double X;
 public double Y;
}

class DataSeries
{
 public String NamaSeries;
 public List<dataXY> Data;
}

class DataChart
{
 public String Title;
 public String LabelX;
 public String LabelY;
 public int JumlahSeries;
 public List<DataSeries> Datas;
}

public class FxChartDemo extends Application {

    public static DataChart Grafik;
    public static void main(String[] argsk) {
        // GET DATA FROM ARGS
        String _test = "NRT USAGE TREND;TANGGAL;ROWCOUNT;2;EMP;HIVE;0:20|1:300|2:200;0:20|1:30|2:200";
        String[] args = _test.split(";");
        DataChart DC = new DataChart();
        DC.Title = args[0];
        DC.LabelX = args[1];
        DC.LabelY = args[2];
        DC.JumlahSeries = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        DC.Datas = new ArrayList<DataSeries>();
        for(int i = 1; i <= DC.JumlahSeries; i++)
        {
            DataSeries DS = new DataSeries();
            DS.NamaSeries = args[3+i];
            DS.Data = new ArrayList<dataXY>();
            for(int j = 0; j < DC.JumlahSeries; j++)
            {
                String[] _data = args[4+DC.JumlahSeries+j].split("\\|");
                for(int k = 0; k < _data.length; k++)
                {
                    dataXY a = new dataXY();
                    a.X = Double.parseDouble((_data[k].split(":"))[0]);
                    a.Y = Double.parseDouble((_data[k].split(":"))[1]);
                    DS.Data.add(a);
                }
            }
            DC.Datas.add(DS);
        }
        Grafik = DC;
        launch(args); 
    }
    @Override
    public  void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        xAxis.setLabel(Grafik.LabelX);
        yAxis.setLabel(Grafik.LabelY);
        xAxis.setAnimated(false); 
        yAxis.setAnimated(false); 
        LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
        lineChart.setTitle(Grafik.Title);
           for(int i=0; i<Grafik.JumlahSeries; i++)
           {
               XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
               series.setName(Grafik.Datas.get(i).NamaSeries);
               for(int j = 0; j< Grafik.Datas.get(i).Data.size(); j++)
               {
                  series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(Grafik.Datas.get(i).Data.get(j).X, Grafik.Datas.get(i).Data.get(j).Y));
               } 
               lineChart.getData().add(series);
           }
        lineChart.setAnimated(false); 

        Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart, 800, 600);
        saveAsPng(lineChart, "chart.png");

    }
    public static  void saveAsPng(LineChart lineChart, String path) {
        WritableImage image = lineChart.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
        File file = new File(path);
        try {
            ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), "png", file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

thx,

Comment: Please edit the question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), minimal code that is complete that somebody could just copy and paste to replicate the issue (hardcode the sample data into the mcve similar to the Oracle sample code you linked).

Comment: @jewelsea, code edited, help me thx..

Comment: @james, haha, stupid of me,  thanks bro....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parse logic in your main method is wrong: you have too many nested `for` loops. Consequently, each of the `DataSeries` instances you create contains *all* the data points. When the data series are plotted, they are identical (so the second one obscures the first and is the only one you see) and each joins all the points in the data set.

You need to eliminate the middle `for` loop:

```
public static void main(String[] argsk) {
    // GET DATA FROM ARGS
    String _test = "NRT USAGE TREND;TANGGAL;ROWCOUNT;2;EMP;HIVE;0:20|1:300|2:200;0:20|1:30|2:200";
    String[] args = _test.split(";");
    DataChart DC = new DataChart();
    DC.Title = args[0];
    DC.LabelX = args[1];
    DC.LabelY = args[2];
    DC.JumlahSeries = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
    DC.Datas = new ArrayList<DataSeries>();
    for(int i = 1; i <= DC.JumlahSeries; i++)
    {
        DataSeries DS = new DataSeries();
        DS.NamaSeries = args[3+i];
        DS.Data = new ArrayList<dataXY>();
        String[] _data = args[3+DC.JumlahSeries+i].split("\\|");
        for(int k = 0; k < _data.length; k++)
        {
            dataXY a = new dataXY();
            a.X = Double.parseDouble((_data[k].split(":"))[0]);
            a.Y = Double.parseDouble((_data[k].split(":"))[1]);
            DS.Data.add(a);
        }
        DC.Datas.add(DS);
    }
    Grafik = DC;
    launch(args); 
}
```

Comment: can i ask you something else ?,  i get error when run above my program : ( Failed in XOpenDisplay, Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:), what is the meaning of this error ??